# Doubt about Chi square distribution

Tags: statistics

I have a dice with six faces. Suppose out of $N$ trials I get outcome with frequencies $f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4,f_5,f_6$. Let the dice is unbiased. 
Then
\begin{equation}
\chi^2= \sum_{i=1}^6 (f_i-N/6)^2/(N/6)
\end{equation}

follows Chi square distribution of 5 degrees of freedom. On the other hand 
\begin{equation}
N_i=\frac{(f_i-N/6)}{N\times (1/6) \times (5/6)  }
\end{equation}

follows standard Normal distribution for $1 \leq i \leq 6$.
Sum of square of independent Normal gives Chi square. Here of course $N_i$ are not independent. How one can find first equation using second equation.

$N$ is sufficiently large.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at two *approximate* statements: (1) the chi-sqared goodness-of-fit statistic is approximately distributed as $\mathsf{chisq}(5),$ provided
$N$ is large enough. (2) A binomial random probability can be approximated by using the standard normal distribution, provided $N$ is large enough. I have never seen a proof directly connecting these two.

*Very roughly speaking,* in the chi-squared GOF statistic, $f_i$ can be viewed as
approximately $\mathsf{Pois}(\lambda = N/6).$ Then $E(f_i) = Var(f_i) = \lambda.$
Upon standardizing, $Z_i = (f_i - \lambda)/\sqrt{\lambda}$ is approximately standard normal.
If the $f_i$ were independent, we would have $\sum_{i=1}^6 Z_i^2$ distributed approximately as $\mathsf{Chisq}(6).$ But there is a linear constraint that
the $f_i$ must add to $n,$ which "reduces the dimensionality" (or degrees of freedom) by $1$, so $\sum_{i=1}^6 Z_i^2$ is approximately $\mathsf{Chisq}(5).$

Something like this argument was given by Karl Pearson around 1900.[Ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodness_of_fit) A rigorous
proof would involve the convergence of a conditional distribution to  $\mathsf{Chisq}(5).$However, many applications of this GOF statistic
are for relatively small $N$, so asymptotic arguments are not entirely
persuasive. Many simulation studies have shown that for expected counts
($N/6$ in your case) at least $5$ the approximation is good enough in
the tail of the distribution to be used for hypothesis testing at reasonable
levels such as 5%.